# Angular.js Directive Template - If Then Conditional For What Template To Use

Tags: angularjs

In angular.js, for the directive I would like to specify the property of the `template` key according to what the `attr.checkType` is using with `if then`. How could I do this? The only place I know to place logic would be in the link function, but the template key/property goes outside the link function.

```
angular.module('monitorApp')
.directive("countDown", [ 'sseHandler', function (sseHandler) {
    function _bindMessage(scope, message) {
        scope.countFrom = message;
    }
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            countFrom: "=",
            checkType: "@"
        },
        //WOULD LIKE TO PLACE IF THEN TO SPECIFY WHAT TYPE OF TEMPLATE TO
        //USE ACCORDING TO ATTR.CHECKTYPE. 
        template :  if (attr.checkType == "foo") {
                      '<div class="btn btn-block btn-inverse" id="api-time">'+
                      'Next update in &nbsp <span class="info-test">{{countFrom}}</span>'+
                      '&nbsp seconds} else
                       { 
                          <h1> HI </h1> 
                       },

        link: function(scope, element, attr){
           scope.countFrom = sseHandler.broadcastStamp[attr.checkType] || "initializing";
           scope.$on('ONE_SEC', function() {
               resultType = attr.checkType;
               seconds = sseHandler.broadcastStamp[attr.checkType];

               if (seconds < -3) {
                   seconds = "Snap! Broadcast is late." +
                          " Something is broke";
               }
               else if (seconds <0) {
                   seconds = "running a little late";
               } 
               _bindMessage(scope,seconds);
           });
        }
    }
}]);
```

Answer (score 1):

You simply need to use a single template, and use ng-if inside the template:

```
template : '<div>' +
               '<div ng-if="checkType == 'foo'" class="btn btn-block btn-inverse" id="api-time">'+
                  'Next update in &nbsp <span class="info-test">{{countFrom}}</span>'+
                  '&nbsp seconds}' +
               '</div>' +
               '<h1 ng-if="checkType != 'foo'">HI</h1>' +
           '</div>'
```

Answer (score 1):

Below you'll find a directive that choose among a list of templates according to the "temp" attribute value

```
module.directive('templateSwitch', ['$compile', function ($compile) {
var getTemplate = function (Type) {
    var typelist = {
        template1: '<div>view1</div>',
        template2: '<div>view2</div>'
    };
    return typelist[Type];
}
return {
    restrict: 'E',
    link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
        var templatelinker = function (listType) {
            var html = getTemplate(listType);
            element.html(html).show();
            $compile(element.contents())(scope);
        };
        templatelinker(attrs.temp);
    }
};
}])
```

Use it as follow

```
<template-switch temp="template2"></template-switch>
```